# Symfony: NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /lucky/number"

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm newbi with symfony, i'm trying to add a new page to the demo application, 
I'm following this [tuto](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html)

I added this controller src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/lucky/number")
 */
 public function numberAction()
 {
    $number = rand(0, 100);

    return new Response(
        '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
    );
  }
}
```

app/console router:debug return:

```
 Name                     Method   Scheme Host Path

 _wdt                     ANY      ANY    ANY  /_wdt/{token}

 _profiler_home           ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/

_profiler_search         ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search

_profiler_search_bar     ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search_bar

_profiler_purge          ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/purge

_profiler_info           ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/info/{about}

_profiler_phpinfo        ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/phpinfo

_profiler_search_results ANY      ANY    ANY   /_profiler/{token}/search/results

_profiler                ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}

_profiler_router         ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/router

_profiler_exception      ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception

_profiler_exception_css  ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception.css

admin_index              GET      ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/admin/post/

admin_post_index         GET      ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/admin/post/

admin_post_new           GET|POST ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/admin/post/new

admin_post_show          GET      ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/admin/post/{id}

admin_post_edit          GET|POST ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/admin/post/{id}/edit

admin_post_delete        DELETE   ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/admin/post/{id}

blog_index               ANY      ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/blog/

blog_index_paginated     ANY      ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/blog/page/{page}

blog_post                ANY      ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/blog/posts/{slug}

comment_new              POST     ANY    ANY    /{_locale}/blog/comment/{postSlug
}/new
app_lucky_number         ANY      ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/lucky/number

security_login_form      ANY      ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/login

security_login_check     ANY      ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/login_check

security_logout          ANY      ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/logout

homepage                 ANY      ANY    ANY  /{_locale}
```

When i navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/lucky/number, i got this error

```
NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /lucky/number"
```

My routing.yml

```
app:
resource: @AppBundle/Controller/
type:     annotation
prefix:   /{_locale}
requirements:
    _locale: %app_locales%
defaults:
    _locale: %locale%

# These lines define a route using YAML configuration. The controller used by
# the route (FrameworkBundle:Template:template) is a convenient shortcut when
# the template can be rendered without executing any logic in your own   controller.
# See   http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html
homepage:
path: /{_locale}
requirements:
    _locale: %app_locales%
defaults:
    _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
    template:    'default/homepage.html.twig'
    _locale:     "%locale%"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php pointing correctly to your symfony project?

Comment: and when you try  http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/en/lucky/number ? you have {_locale} defined before that route

Comment: What does your routing.yml in /app/config look like?

Comment: @AG21 it points to the project

Comment: @vodich the links 127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/en/lucky/number works

Comment: @Koalabaerchen, i edited my question with  my routing.yml code

Comment: @vodich how to redefine the route to be withou the {_locale} variable?
Thanks

Comment: You should implement the [framework:default_locale](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#default-locale) option in your config.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove part with `locale` in your route-prefix if you don't want to manage it:

```
prefix:   /{_locale}
requirements:
    _locale: %app_locales%
defaults:
    _locale: %locale%
```

Your routing file must look like this:

```
app:
    resource: @AppBundle/Controller/
    type:     annotation

homepage:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:    'default/homepage.html.twig'
```

Comment: i accept this answer, and i suppose that there's a mistake in the tutorial since there's no locale variable in the url, in the tuto

Comment: I don't see in the tutorial any information about `routing.yml`. I think that you used `routing.yml` that are not related to this tutorial and so you faced with this problem.

Comment: I am getting the same error, but this does not work.

Comment: If you have the same exception it does not mean that you have the same problem. Try to create new question with your problem and someone here will help you.